# C# WPF textbox GotFocus SelectAll not working

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a textbox with a `GotFocus()` event. The event is supposed select all text in the textbox, but it only works when I set a breakpoint on the `textbox.SelectAll()` command or when I step through the method. I've noticed that when I click on the textboxs bottom border it sometimes selects all.

Can anybody tell me what's going on?

The TextBox_GotFocus() method is as simple as it gets, but here it is:

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox.SelectAll();
}
```

Edit:
My problem isn't that I don't know how to select all and the way I'm using it should work in my mind (I've used it the same way in other apps without problems). The problem is that it only works when I set a breakpoint in the method or step into the method in debugging but not when selecting the textbox in real time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following should help you to select all text.

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus(objetc sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var txtControl = sender as TextBox;
     txtControl.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
     {
       txtControl.SelectAll();
     }));
}
```